# Failed to make 404 page in tornado with nginx

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-404, tornado

I tried to make custom 404 page for tornado and want to deploy it with nginx but failed.

here is my domain.conf(included by nginx.conf)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name vm.tuzii.me;

    client_max_body_size 50M;

    location ^~ /app/static/ {
        root ~/dev_blog;
        if ($query_string) {
            expires max;
        }
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        rewrite (.*) /static/favicon.ico;
    }
    location = /robots.txt {
        rewrite (.*) /static/robots.txt;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    location /404.html {
        root /home/scenk;
        internal;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://frontends;
    }
}
```

But after reload nginx, nothing happen. It seems like tornado catch the 404error before nginx.
I have no idea to solve this problem.

**PS. I just want to make 404error by nginx. But not rewrite 'write_error' in tornado source.**

```
Environment: Ubtuntu 12.04 Tornado2.4.1 runsite with supervisor by Nginx 4 process.
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem and what you actually need is this set:

proxy_intercept_errors on;

From [nginx proxy module documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule):

proxy_intercept_errors

Syntax: proxy_intercept_errors on | off

Default:    off

Context:     http

This directive decides if nginx will intercept responses with HTTP status codes of 400 and higher.

By default all responses will be sent as-is from the proxied server.

If you set this to on then nginx will intercept status codes that are explicitly handled by an error_page directive. Responses with status codes that do not match an error_page directive will be sent as-is from the proxied server.

Answer (score 1):

Finailly solve this problem. Because

```
proxy_pass_header Server;
```

So the real TornadoServer is sent. To hide real server, simply change

```
proxy_pass_header User-Agent;
```

That's all.